# android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout distorts on smaller screen devices android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I am using Grid Layout from v7 support library to create a Grid Layout in android. The Layout builds perfectly fine on larger screen devices(screen sizes > 4"), which I confirmed from previewing screens in android studio. But the layout distorts badly on smaller screen devices (checked on a real device too) with only the first row being visible till the end the screen. Following are the screenshots:

[image: On a smaller screen device]

On a small screen device (Galaxy S in this case)

[image: On a larger screen device]

On a larger screen device (5.1" in this case)

Below is the code for the same:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BDBDBD"
    android:padding="3dp"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_row="0"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu11"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu1_img"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu1_txt"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/menu2"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        app:layout_row="0"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu12"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu2_img"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu2_txt"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        app:layout_row="0"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu13"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu3_img"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu3_txt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/menu4"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu14"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu4_img"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu4_txt"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/menu5"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu15"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu5_img"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/menu5_txt"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        android:id="@+id/menu6"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu16"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu6_img"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu6_txt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/menu7"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu17"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu7_img"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu7_txt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        android:id="@+id/menu8"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu18"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu8_img"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu8_txt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="buttonActions"
        android:id="@+id/menu9"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu19"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu9_img"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/menu9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu9_txt"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Help in this regard, to solve compatibility issue on small devices would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find this [blog post on GridLayout](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html) helpful. Or it might be easier for you to eliminate the GridLayout and just use [LinearLayout with weights](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

Comment: Just got the complete working layout with LinearLayout with weights and works on every device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach using LinearLayouts with weights

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ttl.thetravellerslounge.TopNavigation">
<include
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"></include>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="TTL Immigration"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    />
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:clickable="true"

            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu11"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/menu1_img"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/menu1_txt"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"

            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu12"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/menu2_img"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/menu2_txt"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu3"

            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu13"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu3_img"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu3_txt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu4"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu14"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/menu4_img"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/menu4_txt"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu5"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu15"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/menu5_img"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/menu5_txt"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu6"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu16"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu6_img"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu6"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu6_txt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/menu7"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu17"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/menu7_img"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu7"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu7_txt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="buttonActions"
            android:id="@+id/menu8"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu18"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu8_img"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu8"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:onClick="buttonActions"
                android:id="@+id/menu8_txt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="socialDialog"
            android:id="@+id/menu9"
            >
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/menu19"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:onClick="socialDialog"
                android:id="@+id/menu9_img"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/menu9"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:onClick="socialDialog"
                android:id="@+id/menu9_txt"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```